# Is there any difference between the_title() and echo get_the_title()?

Tags: loop, get-the-title

Just a small question. Is there any difference in using

```
<?php the_title() ?>
```

or

```
<?= get_the_title() ?>
```

Yeah, I know somebody can consider using short echo tag a bad practice, I just want to know is there any difference in result of calling these two functions.

Comment: why is short echo tag bad practice?

Comment: short echo tag is excellent practice it removes the superfluous clutter of php end echo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two are not 100% identical, though they are close.

1. `the_title()` will `echo` content *by default* but the third
   parameter can be used to change that default.
2. `the_title()` prepends the optional `$before` and appends the
   optional `$after` arguments. If theme or plugin code uses these
   arguments the output of the two functions will be different.

If you [take a look at the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L32), the differences are easy to spot:

```
32  /**
33   * Display or retrieve the current post title with optional content.
34   *
35   * @since 0.71
36   *
37   * @param string $before Optional. Content to prepend to the title.
38   * @param string $after  Optional. Content to append to the title.
39   * @param bool   $echo   Optional, default to true.Whether to display or return.
40   * @return string|void String if $echo parameter is false.
41   */
42  function the_title( $before = '', $after = '', $echo = true ) {
43          $title = get_the_title();
44  
45          if ( strlen($title) == 0 )
46                  return;
47  
48          $title = $before . $title . $after;
49  
50          if ( $echo )
51                  echo $title;
52          else
53                  return $title;
54  }
```

You can see that `the_title()` pulls data using `get_the_title()` on its first line, so at that point the two are the same. But `the_title()` then does additional manipulation, potentially.

The same is true of some of the other "echo"/"not echo" functions such as `the_content()` and `get_the_content()`. While close, they are not exactly the same.

Comment: So, technically calling "the_title('', '', false);" would be the same as calling "get_the_title();". Not that I want to use it like that. :)

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Answer (score 3):

```
the_title()
```

will echo the title for you and can only be used within 'the loop' https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

```
get_the_title()
```

without the `echo` or `<?=` will simply return the title. So you could store it in a variable and manipulate it if you needed to 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: So echo get_the_title() has the exactly same result as calling the_title() ?

Comment: yes it does. Please see the links above for more information from the docs

Comment: That's what I thought, i just had some doubts I wanted to clear.